# How to decode a string using com.google.common.hash.Hashing

Tags: java, hash

I have a string that I have hashed using

```
Hashing.sha256().hashString("abc", Charsets.UTF_8).toString()
```

Now I want to decode the encrypted string. How should I do so?

The library I am using right now is
`com.google.common.hash.Hashing`

Comment: yes, you get it right I want the exact same string.

Comment: One doesn't "decode" a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). A hash function is *not* bijective.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the original string, `sha256` is *specifically* designed to make that almost impossible.  If it was possible to do that efficiently then `sha256` would be useless and everyone would be sad.

If you want it to be reversible, you should use an encryption algorithm, which is different from a hashing algorithm.  Reversing a hash, especially a cryptographic hash function, is supposed to be hard.

(In addition, more than one string may have the exact same hash code, meaning that you can't be sure a string with the same hash was actually the same as the original string you used.)

Comment: So what do you suggest, in this case.

Comment: In this case I suggest either changing from sha256 to an encryption algorithm intended to be reversible, or if that isn't possible, then giving up.

Comment: Or, if the contained information is not sensitive, use something like `base64`. Saves the key handling.